# Github workflow to deploy a Laravel application

Tags: laravel, github, github-actions

**Git\Github beginner here.**

After much googling, I managed to make the following Github-action\workflow to deploy a Laravel app on a live testing server.

I just basically need the workflow to update the app files on the testing live server with the latest versions in the repository.

The code seems to work fine, but there are a couple of lines I don't fully understand.

**1)** What is the purpose of the Checkout step (the one using actions/checkout@v2) ?

**2)** What is the purpose of "git checkout -f" in the deployment script ? Is it needed ?

**3)** Is there something I'm missing \ should add in the deployment script ?

**4)** Another thing I'd like to do, would be to "copy" the code that is being pushed to the live server into another repository branch, to keep track of what is currently on the live server. How would I do that in this same action ? (If that makes sense and\or it is even possible)

```
    name: DEV Deploy
    
    on:
      workflow_dispatch:
    
    jobs:
    
      deploy:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
        steps:
          - name: Checkout
            uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
          - name: Deployment
    
            uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
    
            with:
              host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
              username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
              key: ${{ secrets.KEY }}
    
              script: |
                cd /home/app/public_html
                
                php artisan down
                
                git checkout -f
                git branch -u origin/dev
                git pull
                
                composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
                
                npm install
                npm update
                npm run production
                
                php artisan cache:clear
                php artisan view:clear
                php artisan config:cache
                php artisan up
```

Thanks.

Comment: "... to keep track of what is currently on the live server". I believe that is what your master branch is supposed to be.

Comment: @IGP Well, its a little more complicated than that, there are a couple of other people working on the project, pushing changes to that branch. So the idea was to have some sort of "common live testing environment" other than the local ones everyone has.

Comment: Regarding your first question: When you want to manipulate elements from the current repository, you need to use the `actions/checkout`.

This will allow you to access the repository `$github_workspace` (one of Github environment variables) in your workflow.

For example, you can use the `cd` command to navigate the repository thanks to the checkout action, or execute a script file at the root of the repo.

Comment: Regarding your second question: The -f flag is used to force a Checkout.
You can pass the `-f or --force` option with the git checkout command to force Git to switch branches, even if you have un-staged changes (in other words, the index of the working tree differs from HEAD). Basically, it can be used to throw away local changes.

Comment: Regarding your third question: My suggestion would be to create a separate file in your repository with your script and execute it in your workflow. You could even add comments there to explain what does each step of your automation (could help for maintenance if you're not the only one working on it).

Comment: Regarding your fourth question: You could create another script to copy the code to another branch using git commands (with the `action/checkout`). Or even create another workflow that could be triggered on push or pull_request to a specific branch. I believe there are many different (and valid) solutions to do so.